# How to add grid background to canvas? (fabricjs)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I created a canvas in HTML5 and painted the grid on it.

After I added the rectangle through fabricjs and my painted grid disappeared! I don't want that the grid disappeared.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided my problem as follows:

1) I've saved my canvas to base64

2) I've set my saved canvas (base64) as background for fabricjs canvas

My code (coffeescript):

```
gridImageFromCanvas = @canvas.toDataURL()
backgroundImage = new Image()
backgroundImage.onload = =>
  fabricaBackgroundImage = new fabric.Image(backgroundImage)
  @canvasFabric.setBackgroundImage(fabricaBackgroundImage)
  @canvasFabric.renderAll()
backgroundImage.src = gridImageFromCanvas
```